# How do you attach to a remote Java debugger using Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jdb

I am trying to configure Visual Studio Code so that I can use it instead of IJ for debugging a complex Java app. Because of reasons too complicated to get into, I have been running on a terminal using mvnDebug then connecting using JDB. In IJ I set this up as a remote debugger, however, I can't seem to find the same option in VSC.

I have [tried this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.javadebugger) extension, but I can't figure out how to configure it for just JDB (I shouldn't need startupClass etc).

How do I use JDB with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I'm still wondering in 2018

Comment: Still relevant in 2021 @GabrielBB :D

Comment: Still relevant in 2022

Comment: Still relevant in 2023.

Comment: Still relevant in 2024

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Create a Debug Configuration like below and press **F5** to debug :

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Attach)",
        "projectName": "Your_Project_Name",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "your_host_name",
        "port": Debugging_port
    }
]
```

Example :

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Attach)",
        "projectName": "MyApplication",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "port": 8787
    }
]
```

I am using wildfly server. So the default debugging port is **8787**.

Comment: When using Wildfly, you have to start the server with debug option:

stanadalone.bat --debug 8787

Comment: Thanks! I use gradle task with [JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) so adding `debugOptions` section did the work for me in order to connect

Comment: How to do the same, that is, remote debug Java web application running on Tomcat from vs code?

Comment: How can you pass arguments for the remote JVM? (e.g. `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`)