# Remote debug Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, remote-debugging

I've a simple (dockerized) Web Application in Spring Boot.

The App compile correctly.
The container build fine without errors.
The App is running fine on localhost:8080, It's a simple "Hello World".

Now I'm trying to attach Spring Tool Suite debugger to the containerized JVM with Remote debugging but without success.

The fault message is

```
Failed to connect to remote VM com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.ClosedConnectionException
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
WORKDIR /
EXPOSE 8080 8000
COPY target /
```

and that's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8000:8000"
    command: java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=127.0.0.1:8000 -jar gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar
```

In Spring Tool Suite I have these settings for remote debugging:

```
Remote Java Application
- Connection type: Standard (Socket attach)
- Host: localhost
- port: 8000
```

I'm using a Macbook Pro with OSX Mojave (10.14.6)
Thanks for any suggetion.

Comment: try with `address=8000`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

The incorrect part is `address=127.0.0.1:8000` it should be `0.0.0.0:8000`

Full command in the docker compose:

```
command: java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:8000 -jar gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar
```

**Long answer:**

Every container has its own network interface, keeping that in mind `127.0.0.1` means loopback interface and its only accessible from the same host (ie. if you are inside the container you can access it).

In contrast if you want the application to listen on every network interface available, we can swap it with `0.0.0.0` which is in our case what we want, because we are connecting from outside of the container to the debugging port which is 8000 inside the container so loopback interface is not sufficient.

Comment: Yes! Everywhere else I've seen this as address=*:8000, which at the very least doesn't work in the docker-compose context... It's worth noting that you may see a log message like "Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - connection prematurally closed". At first I thought this meant that the connection was dead or Tomcat gave up or something, but was able to connect the debugger and everything seemed to start properly, so don't worry about that message!

Comment: omg your comment has just saved another sad soul (mine) from my countless hours of troubleshooting because I used `127.0.0.1`, thank you sir!!